# Forming a non-singular square matrix from a rectangular matrix with linearly independent columns

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a $m \times n$ matrix, where $m > n$ and all the columns are linearly independent, e.g.
$$
  A = \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    9 & 7 & 10 \\
    6 & 12 & 18 \\
    8 & 9 & 5 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
  \end{matrix}
  \right)
$$
I want to form a square matrix $A'$ by removing rows from $A$ such that the columns are still linearly independent i.e. $\det(A') \neq 0$. In this example removing rows three and five gives
$$
  A' = \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    9 & 7 & 10 \\
    8 & 9 & 5 \\
  \end{matrix}
  \right)
$$
with $\det(A') = 90$ but removing the bottom two rows gives
$$
  A' = \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    9 & 7 & 10 \\
    6 & 12 & 18 \\
  \end{matrix}
  \right)
$$
which is singular.

My question is whether this is always possible to do, or whether there are matrices where no matter how I select the rows to remove some columns will become linearly dependent.

Comment: Hint: row rank = column rank.

Comment: It is always possible. You can select the rows by applying gaussian elimination on the rows of the matrix.

Comment: @Gribouillis Ah of course, then I will have a bunch of rows of zeroes which correspond to the rows I can remove from the matrix. Makes sense :)